# Поочередное суммирование нескольких элементов столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], columns=['a'])
```

Рядом нужен второй столбец с суммой 3 следующих элементов первого т.е.:

> 6, 9, 12, 15, 18

Не могу сообразить что делать. Помогите плиз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте скользящее окно:

```
df["b"] = df["a"].rolling(3).sum()
```

df:

```
   a     b
0  1   NaN
1  2   NaN
2  3   6.0
3  4   9.0
4  5  12.0
5  6  15.0
6  7  18.0
```